# Trouble with MeteorJS and Full Calendar

Tags: meteor, fullcalendar

So I have a calendar going in a MeteorJS application and when adding to the calendar externally it displays but only after reload. So my issue is that `refetchEvents` is not functioning as per the below code I have in an events block for that controller:

```
'submit #add-event': function(event, template) {
var title = event.target.title.value;
var start = event.target.startDate.value;
var end = event.target.endDate.value;
var invited = $('select[name="invited"]').val();
var matter = event.target.matter.value;
var where = event.target.where.value;
var description = event.target.description.value;

params = {
  title: title,
  start: start,
  end: end,
  invited: invited,
  matter: matter,
  where: where,
  description: description
}

Meteor.call('addEvent', params);

toastr.success('Event created!');
$('#addEvent').modal('hide');
$('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'refetchEvents' );

event.preventDefault();
}
```

The same is happening in the `rendered` callback for this template (need to reload before displaying new events):

```
dayClick: function(date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
        // Insert the day someone's clicked on
        var invited = [];
        invited.push(Meteor.user().username);

        params = {
          title: 'New Event',
          start: date,
          end: date,
          invited: invited,
          matter: null,
          where: null,
          description: null
        }

        Meteor.call('addEvent', params);

        // CalEvents.insert({title:'New Event',start:date,end:date, allDay: false});
        // Refreshes the calendar
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'refetchEvents' );
    }
```

Any ideas as to how to get `refetchEvents` to work?

I'm using this Full Calendar package - https://atmospherejs.com/mrt/fullcalendar

Comment: Are you loading events from ajax call? Have you use any sources of fullcalendar to load events? Like events (as a json feed), events (as a function), eventSources etc..

Comment: @ChintanMirani Events are loaded in Meteor through a publication that is being subscribed to with the Iron Router controller. By default, this is reactive and is instant with all other implementations in the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I've managed to fix the issue. Was solved by doing asynchronous calls instead:

```
'submit #add-event': function(event, template) {
    var title = event.target.title.value;
    var start = event.target.startDate.value;
    var end = event.target.endDate.value;
    var invited = $('select[name="invited"]').val();
    var matter = event.target.matter.value;
    var where = event.target.where.value;
    var description = event.target.description.value;

    params = {
      title: title,
      start: new Date(start),
      end: new Date(end),
      invited: invited,
      matter: matter,
      where: where,
      description: description
    }

    Meteor.call('addEvent', params, function(error, result) {
      if (!error) {
        toastr.success('Event created!');
        $('#addEvent').modal('hide');
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'refetchEvents' );
      } else {
        toastr.error(error.reason);
      }
    });


    event.preventDefault();
    }
```

and

```
dayClick: function(date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
        // Insert the day someone's clicked on
        var invited = [];
        invited.push(Meteor.user().username);

    params = {
      title: 'New Event',
      start: date,
      end: date,
      invited: invited,
      matter: null,
      where: null,
      description: null
    }

    Meteor.call('addEvent', params, function(error, result) {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'refetchEvents' );
    });

    // CalEvents.insert({title:'New Event',start:date,end:date, allDay: false});
    // Refreshes the calendar
}
```